# Help to begin in assigning specific bits

Tags: c, bit-shift, bit, logical-operators

So I have a problem for my class that I am having trouble getting started on. I am not asking people to do the problem for me, I just would like any nudge in the right direction. I need to create a function in C that when given any 32 bit integer it returns an integer where every 4th bit is set to a 1 starting at the least sig bit. I understand what it is supposed to look like in the end, but getting started I am lost on. We are not allowed to use any for loops or conditionals, just the standard bitwise and logical operators(! ~ & ^ | + << >>). Once again, I am not asking anyone to do this for me, I just would like some help in getting me thinking on the right track. I have seen some of the other posts on here and on other pages, but none seem to click. I understand that you can bitshift a 1 into a certain place x<<3 but going beyond that I am stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
int get_int_with_every_fourth_bit_set()
{
    return 0x88888888;
}
```

Ok, that was mostly facetious. Here's a list of what the bitwise operators do:

- bitwise NOT (`~`): Toggle a bit, 0 to 1 and 1 to 0
- AND (`&`): Set a bit if the bit in that position is set in both operands
- OR (`|`): Set a bit if the bit in that position is set in either operand
- XOR (`^`): Set a bit if exactly one bit in that position is set between the two operands
- Bitwise shift (`<<` and `>>`): Move each bit over the specified amount in the given direction. When shifting left, zeros are added to the least significant bit. When shifting right, a zero will be added if the value is either unsigned or positive.

Here are some bitwise tricks that are good to know:

A bitwise shift left by one is the same as multiplying by two. A bitwise shift right by one is the same as dividing by two, and rounding down.

All powers of two have exactly one 1 bit. To see if a number is a power of two, you can do this:

`return !(x & (x - 1)) && x`

As an example, say `x = 16`, which is a power of two. Then, `x - 1 = 15`, so the values to be ANDed are `00010000` and `00001111`. Since each bit position has a zero in at least one of the two operands, the result is zero. `!0` is true, so check to see if `x != 0`. Since `16 != 0`, the statement returns true. If you try it with a number that is not a power of two and not zero, then the `x & (x - 1)` check will  always be true. So cool!

Another tip: since `0 ^ 0 = 0` and `1 ^ 1 = 0`, you can use XOR to see what bits have changes. For example, if you have two bytes and want to see the bits that changed between then, the XOR of the two bytes will give you a 1 in the position of all bits that have changed.

Comment: Maybe the OP is looking for `a_32bit_int|0x88888888`?

Answer (score 1):

Can you write down (in hex) the 32 bit integer that has every 4th bit set to 1, and all other bits set to 0?

Now, is there an operation you can apply to your input and this magic number, which sets every 4th bit of the input to 1, but leaves the other bits alone?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [bitmasking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29).

> ...*Therefore, to make sure a bit is on, OR can be used with a 1. To leave a bit unchanged, OR is used with a 0.*

So the mask for your case (leaving other bits unchanged) would be:

Binary: `10001000100010001000100010001000`
Hex: `88888888`